# If probabilities $\mu_n\to \mu$ on every open interval of $I$, does $\mu_n\to \mu$ on the union of countable pairwise disjoint such intervals?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I am stuck for hours with the following question which I does not succeed to prove or to disprove (not a homework problem).

Assume that $\mu$ and $\mu_n$ are Borel probabilities on $[0,1]$.
Let $U = \bigcup_k I_k$, where $(I_k)_k$ is a countable family of pairwise disjoint open intervals of $[0,1]$ (open intervals of $[0,1]$ include intervals of the form $[0, \alpha)\subset I$ and $(\alpha, 1]\subset I$).

Given that $\mu_n(I) \to \mu(I)$ for every open interval of $[0,1]$ (hence in fact on every interval of $[0,1]$), prove or disprove that the hypotheses imply $\mu_n(U) \to \mu(U)$.

**Note:** If that can help to solve the problem, I am mainly interested in the case where the $\mu_n$ are discrete probabilities of the form $\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i \delta_{a_i}$, where $\delta_{a_i}$ is the dirac measure at $a_i$.

Answer (score 2):

In the case that you only have finitely many intervals $(I_k)_k$, your desired result immediately follows from additivity of the measure and linearity of the limit:
$$\mu(U) = \sum_k \mu(I_k) = \sum_k \lim_{n\to\infty} \mu_n(I_k) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_k  \mu_n(I_k) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \mu_n(U).$$
However, if $(I_k)_k$ is an infinite family, the interchange of limit and summation poses a problem. In this case you need more information on the $\mu_n$. One example is monotonicity, i.e. that $\mu_n(A) \leq \mu_{n+1}(A)$ for all Borel sets $A$, since in this case you can apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem (Edit: Monotonicity is actually impossible since $\mu_n$ are probability measures, as has been pointed out). Another option is to use Dominated Convergence Theorem, in which case you would need a sequence $(a_k)_k$ of positive numbers such that $\mu_n(I_k) \leq a_k$ for all $n,k$ and such that $\sum_k a_k < +\infty$. Without these assumptions, the best result I can see you obtain is that
$$\mu(U) \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \mu_n(U)$$
by making use of Fatou's Lemma, or as was explained in another answer.

In your example where $\mu_n$ are discrete measures, write
$$\mu_n = \sum_j A_{jn} \delta_{a_{jn}},$$
(assuming that your weights $A_{jn}$ and points $a_{jn}$ depend on $n$, otherwise things might simplify...) you will get
$$\mu(U) = \sum_k \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_j A_{jn} \delta_{a_{jn}}(I_k).$$
Now the limit is stuck between two sums, which means you cannot even exchange the sums. In particular, you will still get problems if your $a_{jn}$ "jump around" too much in your intervals $I_k$ for you to apply any convergence theorems.

Comment: Tobius. Yeah, I thought about all these vague considerations during hours, but you have missed the fact that the $\mu_n$ are probabilities, that is, $\mu_n([0,1]) = 1 = \mu ([0,1]). In particular, there is no possible monotone convergence on every set. Anyway, I would like a counter example if you think this question has.

Comment: Oh that's true, monotone convergence is indeed impossible, that's on me! I tried to think of a counterexample, however I arrived at the same problems as in the other answer. I'll update this when I think of something!

Comment: Please, pay attention to my last comment in the other answer. I think the example doe not hold, but let wait the answer of nejimban.

Comment: Tobius. I temporarily downvote your answer, as it may give the impression you have given a valid example. As you are new and needs points, I will upvote it later.

Comment: Thanks for the support! Also, some food for thought: The union $U$ is not much different from an open interval. I've been thinking about using something like a Cantor set, or rather its complement; this is about as far away from an open interval as we can get.

Comment: Tried to upvote, but they locked for me the upvoting of this answer unless it is edited. Just add a comma, and it will be OK.

Comment: Just did. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

oh my... I finally found the answer, which was quite simple, I can't believe.

Let
$$\mu_n = {1\over n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n \delta_{i/n}.$$

Then $\mu_n((\alpha, \beta)$ tends to $\beta-\alpha$ for every $\alpha,\beta \in [0,1]$, $\alpha < \beta$. Also, $\mu_n([0,\alpha))\to \alpha$,
$\mu_n((\alpha, 1])\to 1-\alpha$ and $\mu_n([0,1]) = 1$.
So, denoting by $\mu$ the usual uniform Borel measure on $[0,1]$, $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ fulfil the hypotheses.

Notice also that $\mu_n(\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]) = 1$ for all $n$.

Now, cover the countable set $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$ by an open set $V$ of measure $\mu(V) < 1$, which is possible by a simple construction.
It is well known that $V$ can be decomposed into a countable union of open intervals of $[0,1]$.
But $\mu_n(V) = 1$ for all $n$, since $V$ contains $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$.
Hence $\mu_n(V)\not\to \mu(V)$.